# Webmin port 25 is blocked

Tags: smtp, centos, postfix-mta, webmin

I have set up webmin on my CentOS server with a few domains. I have also added a test email account but cannot send any emails from my Outlook after configuring the settings for IMAP/STMP server. If I try and telnet to port 25, i get an error. Iptables isn't blocking port 25, postfix server is running and ISP isn't blocking any ports. I have also tried turning off iptables which made no difference.

Any ideas?